# How to find an element with a class from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find elements that have a class. I am using following code. Why is it not working? How can I make it work?

```
$('<div/>').html("<div class=\"markdown\"></div>").contents().find(".markdown")
```

I am trying to get all the elements with markdown class in the string.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Does not make much sense to me at least. Can you reformulate?

Comment: Don't use `contents()`, just use `find()`

Comment: What is your **actual** example? Both answers below are correct (now that the first one's been edited), but they come at it from different angles because your example seems quite contrived, so one or the other may not apply to your real situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without contents you can get **.markdown** element like this:

```
$('<div/>').html("<div class=\"markdown\"></div>").find('.markdown')
```

Contents get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes. (https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```js
let markdownElement = $('<div/>').html("<div class=\"markdown\"></div>").find(".markdown");

console.log(markdownElement[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`contents`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns the **contents** of the element you call it on. [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) looks only at the *children* and other *descendants*, but in your case, `contents` returns the actual `div.markdown` (because it's the contents of the wrapper div).

If your starting point is the wrapper div, then just use `find` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55206923/157247).

If your starting point is the *contents* of the wrapper `div` (I assume you used `contents` for a reason in your example), to find it in this case, you'd use [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/), not `find`:

```js
const result = $('<div/>').html("<div class=\"markdown\"></div>").contents().filter(".markdown");
console.log(result[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if it might or might not be at the top level, you might use a combination:

```js
const contents1 = $('<div/>').html("<div class=\"markdown\">top level</div>").contents();
const contents2 = $('<div/>').html("<div><div class=\"markdown\">nested</div></div>").contents();

const results1 = contents1.filter(".markdown").add(contents1.find(".markdown"));
console.log(results1[0].outerHTML); // 1

const results2 = contents2.filter(".markdown").add(contents2.find(".markdown"));
console.log(results2[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does `.filter` achieve here?

Comment: @Jeto - It finds the element at the top level of the set from `contents`. (I'm rather assuming here that the setup in the OP's code is artificial...)

Comment: Yeah no idea what he's trying to do so we have to guess I suppose. (Didn't downvote, btw)